# Add button to a image

Tags: asp.net-2.0

How do you add a image to a button when you click it and diplay the image and click another button and the image will go off and diplay the other image in Micrsoft viual web devloper in asp.net.

Comment: note: changing a button's image may not always be a good UI design idea....

Comment: Mr. Period: your friend at the end. http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2002/10/11/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ImageButton Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx). A quick tutorial is at [How to: Create a Custom Image Button Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172532.aspx).